# Unable to connect to SSH after generated public key and private key

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

Can some one help ? I have installed openssh (version OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a) in windows 7 and I have generated the public and private keys, however I'm not able to connect to that SSH. I'm getting an error "Connection closed by 127.0.0.1" if I use the command "ssh localhost" .

However I'm able to connect by skipping the public key authentication via "ssh localhost -o PubkeyAuthentication=no"

Output of the command "ssh -v localhost"

> OpenSSH_6.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015 
>  debug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>  debug1: Connecting to localhost
>   [127.0.0.1] port 22.
>  debug1: Connection established.
>  debug1:
>   identity file /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>  debug1:
>   key_load_public: No such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public:
>   No such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
>  debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory
>  debug1: identity file
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
>  debug1: Enabling
>   compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
>  debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.8
>  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
>   software version OpenSSH_6.8
>  debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.8 pat
>   OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
>   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
>  debug1: kex: server->client
>   aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>  debug1: kex:
>   client->server aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none
>  debug1:
>   expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
>  debug1: Server host key:
>   ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:4Lnpmdki8UuIiQtJyZoc2vxu8x9l
>   PVSN4vykW+axilc
>  debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the
>   ECDSA host key.
>  debug1: Found key in
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/known_hosts:1
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
>   received
>  debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
>  debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
>  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
>   received
>  debug1: Authentications that can continue:
>   publickey,password,keyboard-interacti ve
>  debug1: Next
>   authentication method: publickey
>  debug1: Offering RSA public key:
>   /home/Vinoth/.ssh/id_rsa
>  Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `ssh -v localhost`?  That extra output may help run down the problem

Comment: I have added the output , Please adivse

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.